# OS X Yosemite: Make it "really" dark

Tags: macos, accessibility, osx-yosemite

With the latest release of OS X, 10.10, one is now able to make the menubar, the doc and other smaller components become black - or "dark", as they call it.

As a user of the inverse function (an accessibility tool to color-inverse the screen), I wondered if it was possible to turn the entire interface dark.

On OS X 10.6, there was a tool called "ShapeShifter". 10.7 had a few custom tools that would patch some binaries to enable some theming...but it was shareware and broke my OS X to a point where a complete restore was necessary.

Does anyone know of a method that allows OS X 10.10 to turn dark entirely? Like all the finder windows, and system preferences and alike. That would be extremely handy!